# Can't install Intel HAXM for android studio

Tags: android, intel-haxm

I want to run Android Virtual device in my Android Studio but when I tried to do it asked me to install Intel HAXM device , on installing HAXM device I receive this message

[image]

Can Anyone tell me what to do?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to run Android Virtual device in my Android Studio but when I tried to do it asked me to install Intel HAXM device, on installing HAXM device I receive this message.
>
> [image]

The legitimate Intel HAXM driver is digitally signed.  The certificate used to signed the Intel HAXM driver, is supposed to be trusted by Windows, without any additional user action.

If your system doesn’t trust the certificate, that’s an indication your system configuration is to blame, and you should make the appropriate changes so the certificate is trusted.

However, it’s entirely possible you have installed the incorrect driver, that you thought was legitimate.  So you need to make sure whatever source, you used to install the Intel HAXM driver, is actually a legitimate source.

> Can Anyone tell me what to do?

Take the appropriate actions and install the digitally signed Intel HAXM driver.